# Node.js ensure files are closed

Tags: node.js, file, filesystemwatcher, watch

With my js script I am watching a directory for new files and copy them to another location. Other app creates this files.
The problem is that my watch method is triggered as only that external app starts file creation and it is still not full file. Then I copy this trimmed file.

How can I ensure the file is fully created by the external app?

Comment: In your watcher logic, check for this incomplete condition and loop (delaying with `setInterval()`).  Then when complete do the file copy.